# PhpStorm doesn't scroll to line when clicking on a stacktrace path

Tags: phpstorm

I'm not sure if this is set in my config or if it's a bug, but I used to be able to reach the line specified in PhpStorm's stack trace (for example the PHPUnit output panel), now when I click on such links the caret is positioned on the first line of the file.

[image: Stack trace]

When I click on this link it gets me here:

[image: Caret]

---

Edit: This is my plugin list :
[image]

Comment: Please list any custom plugins that you have installed and active. Maybe one of them is interfering. The line number was clearly not picked up when making file name clickable (you should see the difference in colors yourself)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added the plugin list

Comment: You do not have any plugins that I think might have influenced this (at very least based on my experience/knowledge). You may still try to disable ALL custom plugins to see if it will make any difference. At the same time -- do you have anything interesting in `idea.log` file ? (`Help | Show Log in...`)